# My Mysql Query Not Showing Result

Tags: mysql, sql

Having issue with SQL query.

Please make a correct .

```
$getAds=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertises WHERE status='RUNNING' AND adult='1' AND (country LIKE '%$test%' OR country='ALL') AND (device LIKE '%$pabu%' OR device='ALL') ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1");
```

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$getAds=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertises WHERE `status`='RUNNING' AND adult='1' AND (country LIKE '%$test%' OR country='ALL') AND (device LIKE '%$pabu%' OR device='ALL') ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1");
```

status is a key word